# Bad performance for the entity manager commit - Exponential

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager, database-performance

Im using the entity manager JPA with eclipse link 2.3 &Derby db and I have model with 10 entities and for each entity I need to store **1000 records** ,this process takes about 70 sec. I have test it for the same model with 10 entities but with **100 records** the all process with the commit take about 1.2 sec which is great.

the bottle neck is the `entityManager.getTransaction().commit();` which I do just one time after i persist all the data, the commit take more 95% from the all process. 
when I use the JVM monitor I dive in to the commit and I see that one of the class is responsible for almost all commit time ,the class is `org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping`

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/1.0/org/eclipse/persistence/mappings/ManyToManyMapping.html

my entities and the model **doesn't** have any many to many relationship or use any many to many annotation what could be the reason for the Exponential behavior ?

I have noticed that when I remove this two entities the time was saved by 85%

what is wrong with this entities

The navigation is from person which have **cardinality 1** to title award that have **cardinality of N** i.e one person can have many awards...

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "a3_Person")
public class Person {
    @javax.persistence.Id 
    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 20)    
    //// Id;
    private String person_id;
    public String getPerson_id() { return this.person_id; }
    public void setPerson_id(String person_id) { this.person_id = person_id; }

    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 30)    
    //// Name;
    private String person_name;
    public String getPerson_name() { return this.person_name; }
    public void setPerson_name(String person_name) { this.person_name = person_name; }

    //// Awards;
    private List<TitleAward> person_awards;
    public List<TitleAward> getPerson_awards() { return this.person_awards; }
    public void setPerson_awards(List<TitleAward> person_awards) { this.person_awards = person_awards; }

}




@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "a3_TitleAward")
public class TitleAward {
    @javax.persistence.Id 
    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 20)    
    //// Id;
    private String titleaward_id;
    public String getTitleaward_id() { return this.titleaward_id; }
    public void setTitleaward_id(String titleaward_id) { this.titleaward_id = titleaward_id; }

    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 30)    
    //// Type;
    private String titleaward_type;
    public String getTitleaward_type() { return this.titleaward_type; }
    public void setTitleaward_type(String titleaward_type) { this.titleaward_type = titleaward_type; }

    @javax.persistence.Column(length = 30)    
    //// Category;
    private String Cateeheihbadc;
    public String getCateeheihbadc() { return this.Cateeheihbadc; }
    public void setCateeheihbadc(String Cateeheihbadc) { this.Cateeheihbadc = Cateeheihbadc; }

    @javax.persistence.Column()    
    //// Year;
    private String titleaward_year;
    public String getTitleaward_year() { return this.titleaward_year; }
    public void setTitleaward_year(String titleaward_year) { this.titleaward_year = titleaward_year; }

    @javax.persistence.Column()    
    //// Won;
    private Boolean titleaward_won;
    public Boolean getTitleaward_won() { return this.titleaward_won; }
    public void setTitleaward_won(Boolean titleaward_won) { this.titleaward_won = titleaward_won; }

    //// Person;
    private Person Pers_fhfgdcjef;
    public Person getPers_fhfgdcjef() { return this.Pers_fhfgdcjef; }
    public void setPers_fhfgdcjef(Person Pers_fhfgdcjef) { this.Pers_fhfgdcjef = Pers_fhfgdcjef; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of performance optimization outlined here,

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

ManyToManyMapping is also used for the @OneToMany annotation that uses a @JoinTable, are you using this?  In general correctly profiling and understanding a profile can be difficult, so your profile may not be valid.

Please include your code, and a sample of the SQL log, and profile.  You can also enable the EclipseLink PerformanceMonitor,

see,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/monitoring003.htm

If 100 records only takes 1.2s then you could probably break your process into batches of 100 and get 12s instead of 70s.  70s sounds like you have some sort of n^2 issue going on.

Comment: Thanks James!!! I have added the two entities(I was edit my post with those 2 entities) that make the problem can you see what is defined wrong there since Im having different entity with 1 to N that in the same model that not cause to the bad performance ,

Comment: Well, you do have a ManyToMany, person_awards, as that is the default for any collection of entities.  You should use @OneToMany(mappedBy="Pers_fhfgdcjef").  But to know what the performance issue is you would need to include the code you are running and a sample of the SQL log, or profile.

Comment: @James- im having the same issue using the netfilix file.what does it mean actually  if you dont add the annotations for entity with list the JPA translate it to many to many by default?btw how do you see that this file in jean post have many to many?Thanks!